# update cell value in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

When I run the command:

```
su -s /bin/bash -l postgres -c "psql -d host -c 'UPDATE version_table SET version_id='1.2' WHERE version_id=CAST ('1.1' AS character varying)'"
```

It worked well.

But if I changed the version_id to "1.2.1" as:

```
su -s /bin/bash -l postgres -c "psql -d host -c 'UPDATE version_table SET version_id='1.2.1' WHERE version_id=CAST ('1.1' AS character varying)'"
```

I got the following error messages:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ".1"
LINE 1: ...M version_table WHERE version_id=CAST (1.2.1 AS char...
```

It seems more than one dot are not allowed.

How can I get around it?

Thank!

Add: the type of the column is character varying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have fighting quotes. You're using single quotes for the shell command:

```
psql -d host -c '...sql...'
```

And also for quoting strings inside the SQL:

```
... version_id='1.2' ...
```

Try using double quotes for the shell part:

```
psql -d host -c "UPDATE version_table SET version_id='1.2.1'  WHERE version_id=CAST ('1.1' AS character varying)"
```

Or put the SQL in a separate text file and feed that to `psql` via the standard input

```
psql -d host < sql_in_a_text_file.sql
```

Comment: Yes, I do think I got confused for quotes. Actually, the whole command is `su -s /bin/bash -l postgres -c "psql -d host -c 'UPDATE version_table SET version_id='1.2.1'  WHERE version_id=CAST ('1.1' AS character varying)'"`。 So what is the correct quote format?

Comment: @Vivian: Does it work without the `su`? You might need another set of quotes and some backslashes to escape the inner quotes but I'm not sure off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

change the column to some type of character datatype.

Comment: the column is already defined as character varying. But I still got this problem.